# Macro that deletes rows based on specific cell value, then deletes the empty rows below that specific column cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that let's me do *either / or* of what I am looking to do. I am trying to create code that:

1. Finds "NONE" in column "S" and deletes that row, and
2. then deletes all rows below it until it runs into the next populated cell in that row, but continues to search the rest of column "S" for more "NONE".

Here is what I have so far, but is the issue adding another `IF` before or after the `.Rows(i).Delete` or could it be

```
Sub Helmetpractice()
Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "S"
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet

    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(i, TEST_COLUMN).Value2 Like "NONE" Then
          'this is where I am having trouble for the blank row delete
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post some sample data and an example of what the data should look like after the macro has run?

Comment: So your data has a bunch of blank rows interspersed? As you loop through, couldn't you check for both the "NONE" and for a blank row, and delete in either case? You can use If Application.CountA(.Cells(i, TEST_COLUMN).EntireRow)=0 Then to check for empty row.

Comment: I just posted an image of a snippet of the spreadsheet. Essentially looking to delete the "NONE" row itself, delete blank rows below until it runs into the next populated cell in Column S, and continue through until the end. I want the blank rows below "HELMET" to stay and only want blank rows from under "NONE" deleted. In the end, only gray cells with "HELMET" and blanks below that should remain. Actual spreadsheet has 1000's of rows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest modification to your existing code is to just set a variable specifying the last row you want to delete, and then delete everything from the "NONE" row to that "last row" whenever you find the "NONE".

```
Sub Helmetpractice()
    Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "S"
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
        EndRow = Lastrow
        For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, TEST_COLUMN).Value2 Like "NONE" Then
                'Cell contains "NONE" - delete appropriate range
                .Rows(i & ":" & EndRow).Delete
                'New end of range is the row before the one we just deleted
                EndRow = i - 1
            ElseIf Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, TEST_COLUMN).Value) Then
                'Cell does not contain "NONE" - set end of range to be the previous row
                EndRow = i - 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use AutoFilter and SpecialCells

```
Sub Helmetpractice()
    Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "S"
    Dim iArea As Long
    Dim filtRng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Range(Cells(1,TEST_COLUMN), Cells(Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:=""
        Set filtRng = . SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        If .Cells(1,1)= "NONE" Then .Cells(1,1).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    With filtRng
        For iArea = .Areas.Count to 1 Step - 1
            With .Areas(iArea)
                If .Cells(1,1).Offset(-1) = "NONE" Then .Offset(-1).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End With 
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try it now; I'll get back to you in a few